# wapproj msbuild specify code signing certificate

Tags: c#, msbuild, certificate, code-signing, msix

In a CI script to build desktop app running on windows, we have an avaloniaUI app packaged by a `.wapproj` project, we can build it fine locally using a self-signed certificate, but the USB key containing the EV certificate is located on a remote physical server.

In the CI script, I build/package it like so:

```
msbuild -t:restore
msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64 /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x64" /p:Platform=x64 /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=SideloadOnly
```

Now, I want to specify a signing certificate via the CLI command OR prompt me to select one from windows GUI, and I want it to prompt me for security PIN in order to sign the app. (As said above, the key is connected via USB).

Right now I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(4790,5): error APPX0101: A signing key is required in order to package this project. Please specify a PackageCertificateKeyFile or PackageCertificateThumbprint value in the project file.
```

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555454/signing-vsto-code-with-ev-certificate-on-visual-studio-2017

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, but I was asking about how to instruct MSBuild to look for certificates on the machine via a UI prompt, I am not using visual studio

Comment: Look at the last answer.