# Modify connection string in published Net Core project

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, publish

I would like to know where the connection string can be modified in an MVC Net Core project that has already been published, that is, on which the dll has already been generated. Because a web.config is found and 2 appsetting.json is found

Thank you very much for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the connection string in config file, but you need to re-sign the application and deployment manifests after you have edited the config file. Please refer to the following links for more information about this.

[How to: Re-sign Application and Deployment Manifests](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/deployment/how-to-re-sign-application-and-deployment-manifests?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[Resign Clickonce manifest using mage.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004056/resign-clickonce-manifest-using-mage-exe)

Another way is changing the config file in the Visual Studio and then republish the ClickOnce application.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "Web.config" file and there find the connectionStrings tag. Inside there will be an add tag with all other attributes. Edit this  tag as you wish.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DBName" user...../>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I found where it modify the connection string, is in the appsettings.json